# Boot Menu Issues After Dual-Booting Windows 11 and Arch Linux: BIOS Not Recognizing Boot Devices

Tags: linux, arch-linux, boot, windows, dual-boot

I have recently switched my Windows configuration from RST to AHCI to enable dual-booting with Arch Linux on my Acer Aspire 5.  I followed this [tutorial](https://kskroyal.com/arch-win11-dualboot-2024/) to install Arch Linux; however, I encountered an issue during the final steps..
After shutting down, removing the USB drive, and rebooting, my system consistently boots into Windows instead of presenting the GRUB boot menu, where supposedly I would be able to boot Arch. When I access the BIOS, the boot section appears to be malfunctioning as it does not display any boot devices:

[image]

Furthermore, when I attempt to change the boot options manually, the BIOS does not respond as expected:

[image]

If I uninstall Arch Linux following the steps outlined in the tutorial, the BIOS returns to normal functionality:

[image]

As someone new to Linux, I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your tutorial results in the creation of a second EFI System Partition on a disk that already holds one. Although this should be supported, it might be something that is not very thoroughly tested by system firmware programmers, and it looks like your system's UEFI firmware has a bug in handling this situation.

Only a UEFI firmware update (vendors might call it a "BIOS update" for historical reasons) could really fix this.

Because your tutorial (and apparently Arch in general) mounts the EFI System Partition (ESP for short) to `/boot`, it causes the kernel & initramfs files to be placed in there too; that's apparently why it requires a larger ESP. The distributions that mount ESP to `/boot/efi` will place only the actual bootloader files into ESP, and so can usually coexist within the 100MB or so ESP created by (older versions of) Windows.

(The UEFI specification is designed so that multiple OSs can easily share a single ESP.)

If there is no firmware update available that would fix the UEFI bug, then I'm afraid you might have to experiment to find out the exact behavior of the bug. If the ESP of Windows 11 has enough free space for all the files Arch will want to place there, you might try using the single Windows-created ESP for Arch too; with luck, having just one ESP on the disk might be enough to work around the bug.

Otherwise, we must hope that there are other users of Acer Aspire 5 that have encountered the same bug and can share their solutions.